# Power BI - Select top N in "Direct Query" mode

Tags: dax, powerbi

In "Import Data" mode, it would be easy for us to use DAX `RANKX` in order to support TOP N:

```
SupplierRank = IF(HASONEVALUE('Supplier'[name]), 
        RANKX(ALLSELECTED('Supplier'), [SumSpend],, DESC), 
        BLANK()
    )
```

And then we can choose SupplierRank <= 10 on Visual level filter, but on "Direct Query" mode, Power BI desktop prevents to use `RANKX` due to performance. Is there any workaround on "Direct Query" mode.

Comment: Can't you add this measure to your tabular model, rather than PowerBI client?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment Power BI does not support measures in 'Direct Query' mode.
For now you can add this measure on the tabular model level only, or use "Import Data" option for your datasource connection.

You may as well leave your vote [here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/10435572-create-dax-measures-fields-and-tables-in-direct-q) so that Power BI developers will prioritize the development of this feature.